# Python Subprocess wont terminate

Tags: python, image, macos, process, subprocess

I'm having issues actually killing the subprocess spawned to display an image in Viewer. Basically I'm opening pictures from a stack and want to display them for a certain time then kill the subprocess. When running the program it shows the pictures as wanted but I cant get the actual `.kill` or `.terminate` functions to work.

```
class ImageDisplay(ThreadParent):
    def __init__(self, label):
        ThreadParent.__init__(self, label)
    def display_image(self):
        image = ThreadParent.image_stack.pop(0)
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        # Automagically opens in preview @ osx
        p = subprocess.Popen(["open", "file://%s/%s" % (cwd,
            filepath(filename(image)))])
        disptime = displaytime(image)
        print("Displaying image:", image, "for", disptime, "seconds..")
        time.sleep(disptime)
        p.terminate()
        p.kill()
```

All help would be highly appreciated.

All the best

Answer (score 1):

I think `open` will terminate after preview is opened, which means you have no handle to the preview program. Try calling the preview binary instead like:

```
/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview /path/to/image.jpg
```

HTH